# Magento 2: Payment by Credit Card: Status is Pending Payment and will not change to Paid

Tags: magento2.4, credit-card

Magento 2.4. Payments by credit Card would have a status "pending Payment" for a while until Magento creates a new order with status "paid". Now this no longer happens.